# Question mark with your hands

Tags: word-choice, idioms, expression-choice

How do you call a gesture of spreading one's hands and turning them palms up to suggest a question?
As in "what did you just do, man? That was so weird that left me speechless, so I had to raise my hands to show you I'm asking you stuff" or "Huh?"

Comment: How about a questioning gesture?

Comment: Here's your chance to coin one!

Comment: Closest single word would be "shrug" ?

Comment: @mgb, shrug is a gesture but it's not necessarily made with one's hands, could also be with the shoulders

Answer (score 0):

A common phrase for a questioning gesture is "spreading his hands". If emphatic, the phrase might become "spreading his hands wide".

> "How should I know where he went?" he asked, spreading his hands wide.

Answer (score -1):

As with most complex situations, there is no single word in English for the gesture that you are describing.  Instead, a multiword description of what you mean, perhaps as you have just done, is how one talks about it.